# Invertible modules are locally finite free , proof explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

I am trying to understand the *particular argument in* [Lemma 15.102.2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B8I)'s proof. It writes that if $M$ is invertible $R$-module, then

> we have an automorphism $M \rightarrow M$ which factors as 
>   $$M \rightarrow R^n \rightarrow M.$$

Then it says $M$ is a direct  summand of $R^n$. How is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there are homomorphisms $\phi:R^n\to M$ and $\psi:M\to R^n$
with $\psi\circ\phi=\text{id}_M$. Then $R^n$ is the direct sum of
$\text{im}\,\psi$ and $\ker\phi$.

Comment: The problem is I don't see where $\psi$ comes from.

Comment: @CL. If $u\circ v=w$ and $w$ is an automorphism, then compose with $w^{-1}$ and get...